# How to using testrail-api to add result for step

Tags: testrail

The testrail-api have 4 method to update result.
add_result
add_result_for_case
add_results
add_results_for_cases

add_result >> How should I do let me can add result to step?

Answer (score 0):

The [TestRail documentation](https://support.gurock.com/hc/en-us/articles/7077819312404-Results#addresult) includes an example of how to add steps when using the `add_result` endpoint. You need to use the `custom_step_results` field as shown below:

```
{
    "status_id": 5,
    "comment": "This test failed",
    "elapsed": "15s",
    "defects": "TR-7",
    "version": "1.0 RC1 build 3724",
    "custom_step_results": [
        {
            "content": "Step 1",
            "expected": "Expected Result 1",
            "actual": "Actual Result 1",
            "status_id": 1
        },
        {
            "content": "Step 2",
            "expected": "Expected Result 2",
            "actual": "Actual Result 2",
            "status_id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```